# How use script for button which load on page from .post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

Good day.

I get button from data `.post`

Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('.f1_start').on('click', function () {
        alert('hello');
    });

    $('.button_test').on('click', function () {
        $.post("update.php", {
                    ...
            },
            function (data) {
                    ...
                $('#div_test').html('').html(data); 
                //we get <button class="f1_start">test</button>
            });


    });

});
```

When I click on element page with class `button_test` from `.post` in div with Id `div_test` load button with class `f1_start`. But first script `$('.f1_start').on('click',function(){`  not work for this button.

Tell me please why script not working on load of `.post` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `on` but not delegating it properly. **you should always delegate it to the static parent container which is present in the document at the time of inserting dynamic element**

try this

```
 $('#div_test').on('click','.f1_start',function(){
   alert('hello');
  });
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about on delegated event

Answer (score 1):

As you declear the click for f1_start, is not there, you have to declear it on success:

```
<script>
$(function(){



$('.button_test').on('click',function(){
$.post("update.php", {
...
},
function(data){
...
$('#div_test').html('');.html(data); //we get <button class="f1_start">test</button>
$('.f1_start').on('click',function(){
alert('hello');
});
});


});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

.on when used like that will only register once. You can register the event against an object you know will always be present.

You can give it some additional context such as a containing div so this may work better:

```
$('#div_test').on('click', '.f1_start', function(){
  //.....
});
```

You could also register the current .on event you have inside the callback which would have the same effect and be slightly more efficient but in general doing things like that are better done through a proper revealing module pattern to only register events you require.

Also as another note, there is no need to empty the html and then set it, setting it will replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('#div_test').on('click','.f1_start',function(){
    alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#div_test').on('click','.f1_start', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('hello');
});
```

`<button>` is equivalent to a `submit` so you must prevent the default action in jQuery or the page will redirect without ever showing you your alert.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming .f1_start is inside #div_start

Try :

```
$("#div_test").on('click',".f1_start",function(e){
  alert("AWESOME");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

At first, when the "scripts" loads the $('.f1_start')... the "selected element" not exists...

You need to unbind and set click again, once the post is loaded ;)

Comment: @DevlshOne Really? The .on attach an event to the current selected element... if you do that before the element exists... the new element will be loaded without the handler.

I try to explain that to Leo Loki, because his question is: 

Tell me please why script not working on load of .post ?

But, maybe i'm wrong.. explain me why :(

Comment: `.on()` is used for delegation. It binds to elements existing and those that may exist in the future.

Comment: @DevlshOne, according to the docs, .click is an alias of .on('click')... 

Then, that's the reason of my error... With click, doesn't works for future elements... 

Yo can see an basic example here: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Amzc9/). So, whats happening? Tecnically, that should works, no?

:(

Comment: Sorry for doblepost.. but... its my fault again! Not delegating properly :( 

I'm feel noob :(